# MySQL 'Error Code: 1045' trying to LOAD DATA INFILE in an Amazon RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to add a few hundreds of registers in a MySQL table in an Amazon RDS instance and when I do:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/file.csv'
INTO TABLE databasename.tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 2. File '/home/user/file.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

If I try using **LOAD DATA INFILE** instead of **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE** I get:

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I'm using MySQL Workbench but also tried from command line.
How can I upload a local CSV into that table?

Comment: The documentation may be a good place to look: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to add flag --local-infile when connecting to mysql using command line mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

the connection should have parameter local-infile=1(on), can be added in code or to advanced connection options in the Workbench